# Create new variable inside of pylintrc file

Tags: python, pylint, pylintrc

I'm coming from a world where we program mostly in C++ and our minimal Python code often uses a mix of Pythonic methods and C++ best practices.

As such I'd like to create some custom regexes for variable naming. Example:

```
^([a-z]+)(?:([A-Z]{1})([a-z]+))+$|^[A-Z][a-z]+(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)*$
```

matches both `camelCase` and `PascalCase`. Sometimes our methods, classes, filenames are `PascalCase` and sometimes they are `camelCase`. The above regex matches both.

Is it possible to create a `pascalCase_or_CamelCase` variable inside of always using the above? There are more examples like this but if one variable can be created based on the above I can follow suit for all the other overrides we need.

Comment: Hmmm. Getting some downvotes. Anyone care to comment on how to approve or where to move this question if this is not the correct forum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a variable in the pylintrc is not possible, the simpler thing to do is to copy paste your regex in each regex option.

You could make a pylint plugin defining your own predefined style, and then it's in python so you can make as many variable as you want.
See https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/messages/convention/invalid-name.html#predefined-naming-styles and https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint/blob/main/pylint/checkers/base/name_checker/naming_style.py

Notice that there is a lot of documentation around invalid-name in the first provided link, creating a custom plugin should not be required.